# Does YUI allow you to sort dates in a datatable?

Tags: javascript, yui

Is there a way to sort dates in yui without having to define your own sorting implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they do.  However, you have to use date objects and define the column as type date in your dataset.  I have found an easier way is to put your dates in to the data set as strings in the following format

```
2010-04-10
```

This will allow you to use the default string sorting function and it will sort the dates properly.  Then just put a formatter on that same column to format the date however you like.